# Whats wrong with my code? Getting redirected to same page

Tags: php, html, sql, database

So if the Material number doesn't match the Input with the data stored in database it should redirect to requestfailure.php page and it doesn't store it in database. If it exists it should redirect to requestsuccess.php and store the value in database.

The problem here is, It works fine but the redirection is not working as im always getting redirected to requestsuccess.php no matter it gets stored or not.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$mnum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mnum']);
$mcat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mcat']);
$mmess = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mmess']);
$mcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mcode']);
$mdev = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mdev']);

//error handlers
//check for empty fields

if(empty($mnum) || empty($mcat)){

    header("Location: ../index.php?index=empty");
    exit(); 

} else {

    //check if the request already exists

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pending WHERE Material = '$mnum'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($resultCheck > 0) {

    header("Location: ../index.php?index=requestalreadyexists");
    exit();                 

    } else { 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO pending (Material, ShopFloor, Message, Code, Device, Description, Location) SELECT '$mnum','$mcat','$mmess','$mcode','$mdev', Description, Location FROM list WHERE Material = '$mnum';";

        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        header("Location: ../requestsuccess.php");

    }

}
} else {

    header("Location: ../requestfailure.php");
    exit();

}
```

Also if anyone can tell me how to debug this and where my if / else is going wrong.

Comment: i think problem is here -   $sql = "INSERT INTO pending (Material, ShopFloor, Message, Code, Device, Description, Location) SELECT '$mnum','$mcat','$mmess','$mcode','$mdev', Description, Location FROM list WHERE Material = '$mnum';";

Comment: Description, Location is should be $Description & $Location and also define them

Comment: @SanjayKumar clearly $Description and $Location don't exist.  Those are the columns they are copying from the select statement.

Comment: The problem is not the database as the logic is properly working (for db). eg. if material number exists it inserts in db, if it doesn't it wont and if it doesn't exist, it should redirect to requestfailure.php but in both cases its redirecting to requestsuccess.php

Comment: SO it required debugging can you try to put echo before $sql = "INSERT INTO and comment the redirection. run the code and get the string try to execute in SQL

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSC5DG0QWQWZ